# get URL of any submission for subreddits

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am trying to use PRAW to get new posts from subreddits on Reddit. The following code snippet shows how I get new items on a particular subreddit.

Is there a way to also get the URL of the particular submission?

```
submissions = r.get_subreddit('todayilearned')
submission = submissions.get_new(limit=1)
sub = [str(x) for x in submission]
print sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PRAW allows you to do this:

To get the submitted link you can use `submission.url`

```
[submission] = submissions.get_new(limit=1)
print submission.url
```

Or if you're looking for the URL for the actual post to Reddit then you can use `permalink`

```
[submission] = submissions.get_new(limit=1)
print submission.permalink
```

Comment: Interesting... `url` doesn't appear to be a documented attribute of `Submission`, and quickly glancing through the code, I can't see where the attribute is actually set. But if it works it works...

Comment: If you print the vars for `submission` you can see what all is available. [This page from the docs](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.0.15/pages/writing_a_bot.html#finding-what-we-need) gives a good example of all available vars for `submission`.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v3.0.0/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Submission.short_link) lists a `short_link` property that returns a shortened version of the url to the submission. It does not appear that the full url is similarly provided, though it seems that it could be reconstructed from the subreddit name and the submission's id, which is stored in `submission.id`.

In summary, use:

```
[submission] = submissions.get_new(limit=1)
submission.short_link
```

to get a link to the submission.

Comment: complains of no such attribute when I try submission.short_link

Comment: I see now that your `submission` is actually a list of `Submission` objects. Pick a submission from the list and try again.

Comment: @lordlabakdas if you want the full URL and not the shortened version take a look at the answer I provided.